# 16.04 - newest kernel cannot be removed

Tags: sound, 16.04, kernel

My sound stopped working after upgrading to `linux-image-4.4.8-040408` (I am using 16.04). I tried the steps specified here [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)

but got stuck when trying to execute

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-`uname -r`
```

with the following error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-4.4.8-040408
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-4.4.8-040408'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-4.4.8-040408''
```

However, the kernel shows up in `grub`:

```
sudo update-grub


Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT     is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.8-040408-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.8-040408-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

So oddly, grub finds the kernel (I can also boot with the kernel), but I cannot re-install or remove it.

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

yields

```
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic                4.4.0-21.37                                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic                4.4.0-28.47                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic          4.4.0-21.37                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic          4.4.0-28.47                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

I would be grateful for any hints on how to either remove the entry from grub, or do a clean re-install of the kernel.

Comment: That was initially a bad idea to install a mainline kernel. Apt-get obviously won't install headers or "extra" for this kernel.  Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` to your question and I will tell you how to remove it.

Comment: I added the information. The kernel got installed by default when I re-installed 16.04 from a bootable USB.

Comment: That kernel could not "get installed" by itself.

Comment: Run `sudo apt remove linux-image-4.4.8-040408-generic`

Comment: As I said, this doesn't work, but yields     `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-4.4.8-040408-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-4.4.8-040408-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-4.4.8-040408-generic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the linux-image-4.4.8-040408 has been manually installed without using Debian packaging.

Boot with `4.4.0-28` kernel selected from the grub menu, then manually delete the `4.4.8` kernel files from `/boot`.

Then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: This worked. Cheers.